# Formatting destination HDD with an unattend.xml file from WDS

Tags: windows-7, images, format, waik

When deploying a Windows 7 image using WDS, everything is as I'd like it to be apart from having to choose the drive and format it. If I forget to do this it installs over the existing partition. I know there is a setting to wipe the HDD to be deployed to but I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

How would I define this in the answer file? What components do I need and at what stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer that you are looking for can be found in the last few posts in this thread:

[TechNet Discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistadeployment/thread/eb95183b-a482-49c0-ab9b-d8000f187eda)